# How to Create Subview as Child as Attached Image programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, parent-child, subview

I Have container UI view and I want add subview as Child By programmatically, how i can do it?

[image]

my Problem Once I animate sub view to out container view  will not make it as child

check this Image
[[image]]

Comment: what did you try? what went wrong?

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:subview]` ?

Comment: yes I tried it [self.vew addsubview : Subview]

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Create a new `UIView` from code and then use method `addSubview` like this

```
let test = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height))
mainView.addSubview(test)
```

x e y is referred on the superview

Comment: please check last image i uploaded it

Comment: You can't. You have to remove this testview from his superview and just then you can add it as subview of a new view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add one view to another view as a subview and as its child  view then ,

Viewcontroller.m

```
 [self addChildViewController:newviewcontroller];
 [self.view addSubview:newviewcontroller.view];
 [newviewcontroller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

now newviewcontroller.view is your child view and subview of Viewcontroller

or

abc.m(uiview)

```
 UIView *v=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
[self addsubview:v];
```

Comment: please check last image i uploaded it